# jQuery tokeninput plugin + passing id to another tokeninput url

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I am using a jquery plugin called jQuery Tokeninput http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ and I am having a logic issue.

```
var country_id = "";
    jQuery("#demo-input-prevent-duplicates").tokenInput(host+"/forms/campaign_location.php?action=country", {
            theme: "facebook",
            hintText: "Enter a Country...",
            placeholder: "Enter a Country...",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            onAdd: function(item) {
                country_id = item.id;

            },
        onDelete: function(){
            hideElements();
        },
        tokenDelimiter: "|",
    });
```

My question here is how would I pass the value  of country_id to the parameter of the below code. I'm not seeing how to do this one on the jquery tokeninput documentation.

```
jQuery("#targ_state").tokenInput(host+"/forms/campaign_location.php?action=stateorprovince&cid="+country_id, {
        theme: "facebook",
        preventDuplicates: true,
        hintText: "Enter a State or Province...",
        placeholder: "Enter a State or Province..."

    });
```

If you'll look on this part of the code, I am passing the country_id that was generated above on the "onAdd". This doesn't work though.

```
jQuery("#targ_state").tokenInput(host+"/forms/campaign_location.php?action=stateorprovince&cid="+country_id ....
```

How would I do that one? Your help would be greatly appreciated and of course, rewarded!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
$("#targ_state").tokenInput(host+"/forms/campaign_location.php?action=stateorprovince", 
{
    queryParam: "cid="+country_id+"&q",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to be dynamic, you have to pass a method to tokenInput which will return the url

```
$("#targ_state").tokenInput(someMethodToReturnUrl, ...)
```

So now every time `tokenInput` makes an ajax call this method will be called and you can return the dynamic url.